# Need help in Append JSON file using ContentMerge in Apache NIFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I'm trying to merge a JSON file which has multiple objects. Below is my Oringinal JSON file.

```
 {
 "applicant": {
        "full-name": "Tyrion Lannister",
        "mobile-number" : "8435739739",
        "email-id" : "tyrionlannister_casterlyrock@gmail.com"
    },
    "product": {
        "product-category" : "Credit Card",
        "product-type" : "Super Value Card - Titanium"
    }
}
```

I will get some more JSON data as below from other source.

```
{
    "flags": {
        "duplicate-flag" : "No"
        "contact-flag" : "Yes"
         }
}
```

My task is to append the new JSON in the old JSON recods as a new object as below.

```
 {
 "applicant": {
        "full-name": "Tyrion Lannister",
        "mobile-number" : "8435739739",
        "email-id" : "tyrionlannister_casterlyrock@gmail.com"
    },
    "product": {
        "product-category" : "Credit Card",
        "product-type" : "Super Value Card - Titanium"
    },
    "flags": {
        "duplicate-flag" : "No"
        "contact-flag" : "Yes"
         }
}
```

Can someone help to guide, how it can be achieved in NiFi ?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend accumulating your components as flowfile attributes, then forming a merged object with an [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) processor using JavaScript/ECMAScript.  Sometimes there's just no substitute for JavaScript.  Something like the following might work:

```
flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile != null) {
    var OutputStreamCallback = Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.OutputStreamCallback");
    var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");

    // Get attributes
    var applicant = JSON.parse(flowFile.getAttribute("applicant"));
    var product = JSON.parse(flowFile.getAttribute("product"));
    var flags = JSON.parse(flowFile.getAttribute("flags"));

    // Combine
    var merged = {
        "applicant": applicant,
        "product": product,
        "flags": flags
    };

    // Write output content
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new OutputStreamCallback(function(outputStream) {
        outputStream.write(JSON.stringify(merged, null, "\t").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }));

    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
}
```